# Load data from REST server instead of local cache in Ember JS

Tags: rest, ember.js, ember-data

I have the following models in an EmberJS REST adapter scenario:

```
App.Brand = DS.Model.extend({
name: DS.attr('string'),
models: DS.hasMany('model', {async: true})
});

App.Model = DS.Model.extend({
name: DS.attr('string'),
brand: DS.belongsTo('brand')
});
```

then I have a route to fetch a single brand record:

```
App.BrandRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function (params) {
    return this.store.find('brand', params.brand_id);
}
});
```

and a route to fetch all brands records:

```
App.BrandsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function () {
    return this.store.findAll('brand');
}
});
```

my problem is the following: if I trig the App.BrandRoute reloading the page, Ember do a AJAX request to the REST server (brands/[brand_id]) and fetch all the data, including relationship. If I start from the index page triggering the App.BrandsIndexRoute first, then if I use a link in the application to trig the App.BrandRoute it doesn't fetch the data from the REST server but it uses local cached data, without relationship (this because the relations are available only in the rest service /brands/[brand_id] and not in the service /brands that displays all brands without relations. How can I force Ember to load data from server instead of local cache when I display a single brand?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: change .findAll('brand') to .find('brand')

Comment: @fanta I'm sorry but it doesn't change anything. When I go to the index route it load all brands without relationship and when I go from this route to the single brand view it fetch the model form the cache. Only if I reload the page http://myhost/brands/123 it loads the record from the rest server...

Comment: ahhh, I now understand what you are asking for. So, you want to fetch the model again ?, this is because you want to load all relationships, etc. Ok, if reloading the model us what you want, I think what you can do is to pass the id of the Brand and not the object, that way the 'model' hook in the Brand Route will be executed again.

Comment: I wasn't very specific, you should pass the Brand id in the link-to helper.

Comment: @fanta thanks, you understand the problem. I just tried changing the link from {{#link-to 'brand' this}}{{name}}{{/link-to}} to {{#link-to 'brand' id}}{{name}}{{/link-to}} but the brand route fetch the record always from local... I could add the relationship 'models':[1,2,3...] already in the /brands REST service, but I would like to avoid this because it could be very bad for the server performance

Comment: Try setting model from setupController hook instead of model hook as setupController is always called unlike model hook whenever the template is loaded.